# Getting warning when trying to pass the address in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I get the warning:

```
expected 'const CHAR *' but argument is of type 'CHAR (*)[18]'
```

Why is the compiler giving me this warning? This is the line I am using to call to the api:

```
AG_AS(g_AgMgrCtx.audio_device.Profile_Type,&g_AgMgrCtx.SDevAddr);
```

The declaration of the function is

```
AG_AS(AG_DType d_type , CHAR *addr);
char SDevAddr[18];
```

What is the problem with passing the address? When I remove `&` the warning goes away.

What does the warning actually mean?

Comment: The address of an array yields a pointer to an array.  Using the array name yields a pointer to the first element of the array.  The types are radically different.  Don't use `&` when you don't need it

Comment: It says that `const CHAR *` is not the same as `CHAR (*)[18]`.

Answer (score 2):

That means your call should be (without the `&`):

```
   AG_AS(g_AgMgrCtx.audio_device.Profile_Type, g_AgMgrCtx.SDevAddr);
```

`g_AgMgrCtx.SDevAddr`is an array of 18 chars. So when you pass it to a function, it gets converted into a pointer to its first element (thus matching the type that `AG_AS()` expects).

Relevant: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 0):

When you have an object like this

```
T obj;
```

where T is some type then expression `&obj` has type `T *` that is it is a pointer to an object of type `T`.

This array declaration

```
char SDevAddr[18];
```

can be transformed to the form shown above using a typedef. For example

```
typedef char T[18];
T SDevAddr;
```

In this case expression `&SDevAddr` has type `T *` as it has been pointed above. however in this case `T` in turn an alias for the type `char[18]`. Thus `&SDevAddr` is a pointer to an object of type `char[18]` Its type looks like `char ( * )[18]`.

However as it is seen from the function declaration

```
AG_AS(AG_DType d_type , CHAR *addr);
```

the second parameter has type `char *`. If you will pass as an argument the array itself like `SDevAddr` then it will be implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and will have type `char *` that is required for the function call.